# Is the following statement on the stability of the forward Euler method true or false?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation

My text asks whether the following statement is true or false:

> The forward Euler method for approximating the solution of $x'=\lambda x$ is stable for all $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ and all step sizes $0<h\leq \frac{2}{|\lambda|}$.

We know that the forward Euler method is unconditionally stable for $\lambda \geq 0$. And if $\lambda<0$ then it's conditionally stable, with $0<h\leq \frac{2}{|\lambda|}$ being the condition.

So the answer to the question seems to be "true". Yet the professor is known for tricky question, so I guess $\lambda = 0$ would cause problems in the question statement (unless we assume $\frac{2}{0}:=\infty$, which we shouldn't in the simple Intro to Numerics course). Another issue I thought of: the problem for the method should be an initial value problem but $x(0)=x_0$ is nowhere to see.

Or putting the initial value issue aside we can write:

$$\forall \lambda \in \mathbb R \ \ \forall h \in \mathbb R \ \ \left(0<h\leq \frac{2}{|\lambda|}  \implies \text{the method is stable} \right)$$

Say, if $\lambda = 0$, what happens with the implication from "not defined"?

Am I over thinking it? Is the statement true/false?

Comment: You could simply write down explicitely the solution of the Euler method (since we are in a case where this is possible) and see what happens.

Comment: @Did: if we treat $\lambda < 0$ and $\lambda \geq 0$ separately, then all good. But I am confused about the $\frac{2}{0}$ issue. Do you think the statement is true or false?

Comment: This is a non-issue: replace this by the condition $h\gt0$, $h|\lambda|\leqslant2$. More to the point, did you write down the iterates produced by the Euler method?

Comment: @Did: yes, it's $x_k=x_0(1+\lambda h)^k$, so we are fine if $\lambda \geq0$, else we need $|1+\lambda h|\leq 1 $ which translates to the condition. What am I missing?

Comment: "What am I missing?" Nothing.

Comment: @Did: so if I understand correctly, the quoted statement is "true" in your opinion, right? Many thanks!